# ui-grid has duplicate rows

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome, ui-grid

I don't know how this started happening but a ui-grid [(project home)](http://ui-grid.info/) on my page (angular SPA) is duplicating 2 rows somehow (and I don't want it to).

Refreshing the page (Chrome) has no effect (I have devtools open, with Disable cache checked).

For reference: I am setting the grid.data to an array with 65 entities, so that count is correct, and if I remove all filters it shows all 65, but actually 67 rows shown (I took the time to count, with the interesting find that alternating rows don't necessarily keep their grey or white color as you scroll up and down).

Here's what I am seeing. If I click row 3 or 4, both are selected and 1 and 2 are unselected. I assume that they have the same generated Id. Note here that it does say that only one row is selected, but 4 are shown!
[image: ui-grid screenshot from Chrome]

I can open the page in Firefox and log in, then go to this page which then looks right, so it is either something in Chrome or something in this instance and other users wouldn't see it.
[image: ui-grid screenshot from Firefox]

Here is the array from the grid.data:

```
[{"Name":"Trainer","Desc":"","Type":"string","OptionsCount":6,"$$hashKey":"uiGrid-000W"},
{"Name":"System","Desc":"Practice","Type":"string","OptionsCount":97,"$$hashKey":"uiGrid-000Y"},
{"Name":"EMR","Desc":"Electronic","Type":"string","OptionsCount":67,"$$hashKey":"uiGrid-0010"},
{"Name":"Guideline","Desc":"Guideline","Type":"string","OptionsCount":7,"$$hashKey":"uiGrid-0012"},
{"Name":"Notes","Desc":"Notes","Type":"string","OptionsCount":4,"$$hashKey":"uiGrid-0014"},
{"Name":"Scorecard","Desc":"April 2015","Type":"string","OptionsCount":27,"$$hashKey":"uiGrid-0016"},
{"Name":"Scorecard","Desc":"July 2015 ","Type":"string","OptionsCount":27,"$$hashKey":"uiGrid-0018"},
{"Name":"Scorecard","Desc":"November 2","Type":"string","OptionsCount":27,"$$hashKey":"uiGrid-001A"},
{"Name":"Scorecard","Desc":"December 2","Type":"string","OptionsCount":27,"$$hashKey":"uiGrid-001C"},
{"Name":"Scorecard","Desc":"September ","Type":"string","OptionsCount":27,"$$hashKey":"uiGrid-001E"},
{"Name":"2012","Desc":"","Type":"money","$$hashKey":"uiGrid-001G"},
{"Name":"2014","Desc":"","Type":"money","$$hashKey":"uiGrid-001I"},
{"Name":"2015","Desc":"","Type":"money","$$hashKey":"uiGrid-001K"},
{"Name":"2016","Desc":"","Type":"money","$$hashKey":"uiGrid-001M"},
{"Name":"2017","Desc":"","Type":"money","$$hashKey":"uiGrid-001O"},
{"Name":"Specialty","Desc":"Primary","Type":"string","OptionsCount":191,"$$hashKey":"uiGrid-001Q"},
{"Name":"Specialty2","Desc":"Secondary","Type":"string","OptionsCount":191,"$$hashKey":"uiGrid-001S"},
{"Name":"Special","Desc":"Special","Type":"string","$$hashKey":"uiGrid-001U"},
{"Name":"Rooming In","Desc":"Rooming in","Type":"date","$$hashKey":"uiGrid-001W"},
{"Name":"HTN","Desc":"Hyper","Type":"date","$$hashKey":"uiGrid-001Y"},
{"Name":"Depression","Desc":"Depression","Type":"date","$$hashKey":"uiGrid-0020"},
{"Name":"Measure","Desc":"measure","Type":"date","$$hashKey":"uiGrid-0022"},
{"Name":"HCC","Desc":"HCC","Type":"date","$$hashKey":"uiGrid-0024"},
{"Name":"Data 1","Desc":"First","Type":"date","$$hashKey":"uiGrid-0026"},
{"Name":"Data 2","Desc":"Second","Type":"date","$$hashKey":"uiGrid-0028"},
{"Name":"Data 3","Desc":"Third","Type":"date","$$hashKey":"uiGrid-002A"},
{"Name":"Term Date","Desc":"Termination","Type":"date","$$hashKey":"uiGrid-002C"},
{"Name":"2015.11","Desc":"11.1.2015","Type":"float","$$hashKey":"uiGrid-002E"},
{"Name":"2016.07","Desc":"7.1.2016","Type":"float","$$hashKey":"uiGrid-002G"},
{"Name":"Status","Desc":"Practice","Type":"string","OptionsCount":3,"$$hashKey":"uiGrid-002I"},
{"Name":"Phase","Desc":"","Type":"string","OptionsCount":5,"$$hashKey":"uiGrid-002K"},
{"Name":"EMFMT","Desc":"","Type":"string","OptionsCount":2,"$$hashKey":"uiGrid-002M"},
{"Name":"LAB Data","Desc":"","Type":"string","OptionsCount":2,"$$hashKey":"uiGrid-002O"},
{"Name":"Phase #","Desc":"Performance","Type":"integer","$$hashKey":"uiGrid-002Q"},
{"Name":"Letter 1","Desc":"Performance","Type":"date","$$hashKey":"uiGrid-002S"},
{"Name":"Letter 2","Desc":"Performance","Type":"date","$$hashKey":"uiGrid-002U"},
{"Name":"Letter 3","Desc":"Performance","Type":"date","$$hashKey":"uiGrid-002W"},
{"Name":"I Term","Desc":"","Type":"date","$$hashKey":"uiGrid-002Y"},
{"Name":"CO","Desc":"CO","Type":"bit","$$hashKey":"uiGrid-0030"},
{"Name":"Chart","Desc":"Chart","Type":"string","OptionsCount":3,"$$hashKey":"uiGrid-0032"},
{"Name":"Test money","Desc":"","Type":"money","$$hashKey":"uiGrid-0034"},
{"Name":"End-testing","Desc":"","Type":"money","$$hashKey":"uiGrid-0036"},
{"Name":"test1234","Desc":"","Type":"string","OptionsCount":5,"$$hashKey":"uiGrid-0022"},
{"Name":"testAbc","Desc":"","Type":"date","$$hashKey":"uiGrid-003A"},
{"Name":"test456","Desc":"","Type":"bit","$$hashKey":"uiGrid-003C"},
{"Name":"M","Desc":"Meaningful","Type":"string","OptionsCount":2,"$$hashKey":"uiGrid-003E"},
{"Name":"test date","Desc":"","Type":"date","$$hashKey":"uiGrid-003G"},
{"Name":"Service","Desc":"","Type":"string","$$hashKey":"uiGrid-003I"},
{"Name":"R Notes","Desc":"","Type":"string","OptionsCount":17,"$$hashKey":"uiGrid-003K"},
{"Name":"Appointment","Desc":"Appointment","Type":"string","OptionsCount":3,"$$hashKey":"uiGrid-003M"},
{"Name":"Connection","Desc":"Type of Connection","Type":"string","OptionsCount":6,"$$hashKey":"uiGrid-003O"},
{"Name":"A","Desc":"","Type":"string","OptionsCount":6,"$$hashKey":"uiGrid-003Q"},
{"Name":"Billing","Desc":"B","Type":"string","OptionsCount":6,"$$hashKey":"uiGrid-003S"},
{"Name":"E Connection","Desc":"","Type":"string","$$hashKey":"uiGrid-003U"},
{"Name":"Addend","Desc":"Data Addend","Type":"string","OptionsCount":2,"$$hashKey":"uiGrid-003W"},
{"Name":"IT","Desc":"","Type":"string","OptionsCount":4,"$$hashKey":"uiGrid-003Y"},
{"Name":"Portal","Desc":"","Type":"string","OptionsCount":5,"$$hashKey":"uiGrid-0040"},
{"Name":"Follow-up ","Desc":"","Type":"string","OptionsCount":3,"$$hashKey":"uiGrid-0042"},
{"Name":"Subspecial","Desc":"","Type":"string","OptionsCount":4,"$$hashKey":"uiGrid-0044"},
{"Name":"T","Desc":"Trainerh","Type":"string","$$hashKey":"uiGrid-0046"},
{"Name":"S","Desc":"","Type":"string","OptionsCount":3,"$$hashKey":"uiGrid-0048"},
{"Name":"A","Desc":"Date","Type":"string","$$hashKey":"uiGrid-004A"},
{"Name":"Dual","Desc":"Date joint","Type":"date","$$hashKey":"uiGrid-004C"},
{"Name":"Start D","Desc":"","Type":"date","$$hashKey":"uiGrid-004E"},
{"Name":"CO Addend","Desc":"Data COA","Type":"string","OptionsCount":1,"$$hashKey":"uiGrid-004G"}]
```

Has anyone else experience this issue with ui-grid, and how did you resolve it?
Or can anyone explain why it is creating these extra rows, and consistently only for these 2 rows?

Comment: Please explain if you have an issue with the question, what the issue is and suggest an improvement before downvoting :(

Comment: I checked and there are 2 rows that are getting selected, they have different GridRow.uids, but the same name.

Comment: can you post some code? your list, your grid definition

Comment: I narrowed it down to this call: gridApi.grid.modifyRows(grid.data).then(action);. If I comment that out the problem here goes away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so here's my answer. I apologize that this wasn't all in the original question, but there was too much code for it to be helpful. I'm writing an answer to be helpful for anyone else that runs into similar issues and gets stuck debugging (as I see that sharing as the purpose of SO).

For background, a row is supposed to get selected during the page load process if the url has an Id for the row as a parameter.

In the code the data is loaded into the grid.data. Then if the url has a parameter a loop executes on grid.data to find the matching row(s). If it is found, then it would call

```
gridApi.grid.modifyRows(grid.data).then(action);
```

where the action would be something like

```
$timeout(function () {
    // Do this after the columns and rows processors have finished and it is all rendered.
    selectRows.forEach(function (row) {
        gridApi.selection.selectRow(row);
    });
    gridApi.core.scrollTo(selectRows.pop(), grid.columnDefs[0]);
}, 100);
```

What is working for me now is to skip the "gridApi.grid.modifyRows" and just call the action. I think that code was in there earlier to update the grid if it had rendered before the data was retrieved and assigned to grid.data, but that is taken care of by waiting for onRegisterApi to fire, then assigning the grid.data.

Comment: Cool. You can also create a directive to do all binds.

Comment: I've same issue with duplicating records but don't understand your solution.